# Функция slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Проблема в том, что при срабатывании функция относит пользователя в самый низ разворачиваемого блока, но к сожалению при обратом действии(сворачивании) она оставляет пользователя в том же низу и не подтягивает его вверх из-за этого если разворачивается огромная секция и потом сворачивается, то пользователь остается брошенным на несколько секций внизу. Вот как сделать что фукнция slideToggle() поднимала пользователя вверх как она это делает, когда срабатывает при первом нажании вниз.

Comment: Это функция jQuery посмотрите у них в справочнике, там есть примеры

Comment: @LiEm Дайте пример рабочего кода.